# Directly go to Product Detail page on click of a category in the nav bar

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

In my store, one of the category has only one product. Is it possible to take the user directly to the product detail page of this one product whenever they click this category in the nav bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this can be done by using the **URL Rewrite Management** option in **Magento Admin**.

In Magento Admin:

1. Select from menu bar **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management**.
2. Click on the **Add URLRewrite** button.
3. Select the **category** you want to redirect from.
4. Make a note of the **ID Path** (e.g.: *category/10*) and the **Request Path** (e.g.: *flowerpots.html*)
5. Repeat steps **1 & 2**, but this time select **Custom** from the **Create Urlrewrite** dropdown box.
6. Enter the values in each field:

   - **ID Path** (from step 4)
   - **Request Path** (from step 4)
   - **Target Path** - enter path of your product (or the page you want to redirect to).

     - *example 1:* for product url ***www.myswebsite.co.uk/flowers.html*** enter ***flowers.html***.
     - *example 2:* for product url ***www.myswebsite.co.uk/sale/garden/flowers.html*** enter ***sale/garden/flowers.html***.
7. Select **Redirect Permanent (301)** from the **Redirect** dropdown.
8. Save.

Now when the category is clicked on on your website it will re-direct to the product.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (CE 1.7.0.2). After recreating all the indexes Magento realizes that the initial category link doesn't work anymore and appends `-1` to the category link in the navigation, bypassing the forced redirection created using the instructions above.

Comment: Step 4.1: Delete the system-created URL rewrite before adding in your own

Comment: @Rodney system creates its rewrites again.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done programmatically by adding code to the page template in your theme folder which is called for showing the categories. Check full solution here - http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2015/01/30/magento-auto-redirect-to-product-details-page-if-category-have-only-one-product/

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the Steps:**

> 1. Open the page template which is assigned to the category pages. You will find it under “template/page/” folder in your theme directory. For example let us assume the page is 1column.phtml (for the One column layout).
> 2. Just after the lines

/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */

> 3. Add the following code :

```
<?php 
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if($product == ''){
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if(is_object($category)){
$catLoaded = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getEntityId());
 $collection = $catLoaded->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
if(count($collection) == 1){
foreach($collection as $product){
 $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
 header("location:$productUrl");
 exit;
  }
 }
 }
} 
?>
```