# Magento how to link a category to a specific product

Tags: magento

I have a Magento 1.7 Web Site and a top menu navigation linking to categories.

Is it possible that a link in the top menu will reference a specific product rather than its category?

Comment: See duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871611/directly-go-to-product-detail-page-on-click-of-a-category-in-the-nav-bar

Answer (score 1):

No there is no direct way to do this.

But you can make category on the menu and Then do Custom URL Rewrite to write that url request path to The product you want.

Check Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management -> Add URL Rewrite

Add url for Product -> Skip Category -> then change the request Path to be the category URL you want to link to product

Its straight forward, This should solve your issue.

Comment: Which 'URL Rewrite' should i choose? 'For Product', 'For Category' or 'Custom'?

Comment: Add url for Product -> Skip Category -> then change the request Path to be the category URL you want to link to product